# OrthoNormal sequence vs OrthoNormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What is the difference between orthoNormal basis and orthoNormal Sequence? OrthoNormal basis is linearly independent and spans, whereas OrthoNormal sequence is not linearly independent and does not span?

Comment: Check this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268471/what-is-the-difference-between-a-complete-orthonormal-set-and-an-orthonormal-bas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An orthonormal sequence does not necessarily span.  However, every orthonormal basis is an orthonormal sequence.

Comment: Can I add that an orthonormal sequence is not necessarily linearly independent and does not necessarily span? In other words, an orthonormal sequence may or may not have the properties of basis, which are spaning and linear independence?

Comment: If a set is orthnormal, it is linearly independent.

Comment: Oh I see. It makes sense, Thanks.